# How can I install LAPACK for gfortran compiler in Visual studio code?

Tags: gfortran, lapack

Can someone please tell me proper instructions to install LAPACK for gfortran compiler in Visual studio code.

I tried whatever l found on google search and there is not a single proper instructions for this and I need this more my computational physics lab?

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. What is your operating system? You install LAPACK in your operating system, the Visual Studio Code editor has nothing to do with that.

Comment: Windows 11 as my operating system

Comment: Do you have gfortran working?

Comment: There are binary releases of OpenBLAS available https://github.com/OpenMathLib/OpenBLAS/releases They include both LAPACK and BLAS. You then need to instruct your linker to link it like any other library.